# CakePHP: HABTM relationship returns join table as an object - how do I get rid of it?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a 2 CakePHP models, Articles and Categories, attached using a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship, like so:

```
$category = new Category();
    $category->bindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
        'Article' => array(
                    'className' => 'Article',
                    'joinTable' => 'articles_categories',
                    'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
                    'associationForeignKey' => 'article_id',
                    'fields' => 'id,name'
                    ))));

$this->set('categories', $category->find('all', 
        array(
            'fields' => 'id,name'
        )));
```

...but then, when I print out $categories, I get the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 31
                [name] => category name
                [article_count] => 1
            )

        [Article] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1445
                        [name] => article name
                        [teaser] => 
                        [author_id] => 3
                        [ArticlesCategory] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6634
                                [article_id] => 1445
                                [category_id] => 31
                                [author_id] => 3
                                [created] => 2014-03-10 12:27:26
                                [modified] => 2014-03-10 12:27:26
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

I really don't need the [ArticlesCategory] member of [Article]. This just leads me back to information I already have. I tried limiting recursion but that didn't help.

How would I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

[1] Reduce recursive value to 0 (CakePHP default: 1)

```
$category->recursive = 0;
$category->find('all', 
        array(
            'fields' => 'id,name'
        ))
```

[2] Start using ContainableBehaviour (my own preference), which gives you more control over model data retrieved

Add following to AppModel for App-wide coverage:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

The find method becomes:

```
$category->find('all', 
        array(
            'fields' => 'id, name',
            'contain' => 'Article'
        ))
```

That should do it!